# Object doesn't support property or method 'transformNode' in Internet Explorer 10 (Windows 8)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I am having some JavaScript issues that seem to only occur in Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 8 (IE 7, 8, and 9 all work fine).  The basic jist of what I am doing is getting XML and XSL from a web service and then transforming them in JavaScript to render on the page using the Sys.Net.XMLDOM object.

```
XMLDOM = Sys.Net.XMLDOM;

var xsl = // XSL gotten from somewhere else 
var xmlString = // XML gotten from somewhere else as a string...
var xml = new XMLDOM(xmlString);

var content = xml.transformNode(xsl);
```

When I use the above code in IE 10, I get:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'transformNode'

Any ideas on why Internet Explorer 10 is doing this?

**EDIT**

I have also tried this:

```
xmldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument"); 
xmldoc.async = false; 
xmldoc.load(xml); 

xsldoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument"); 
xsldoc.async = false; 
xsldoc.load(xsl); 

var content = xmldoc.transformNode(xsldoc);
```

Which works in all previous versions of IE, but in IE 10 I get:

> Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'atom'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx

IE 10 requires using an XMLHttpRequest with the responseType set as "msxml-document".  Once I switched the code over to that, everything works perfectly in all browsers:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For IE 6
}
xhr.open("GET", url, false);
try { xhr.responseType = "msxml-document"; } catch (e) { };
xhr.send();
```

Comment: how would you add the xml to the XMLHttRequest. The context in question and answer doesn't match. I'm a newbie can u please elaborate the answer in line with the question. I'm facing just the similar issue of "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'atom'.

"

Answer (score 5):

IE 9 and grater doesn't support it, try this function ([found online](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2113))

```
function TransformToHtmlText(xmlDoc, xsltDoc) {
    if (typeof (XSLTProcessor) != "undefined") { // FF, Safari, Chrome etc
        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
        var xmlFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
        return GetXmlStringFromXmlDoc(xmlFragment);
    }

    if (typeof (xmlDoc.transformNode) != "undefined") { // IE6, IE7, IE8
        return xmlDoc.transformNode(xsltDoc);
    }
    else {
        try { // IE9 and grater
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate");
                var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
                xslDoc.loadXML(xsltDoc.xml);
                xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
                var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
                xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
                xslProc.transform();
                return xslProc.output;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("The type [XSLTProcessor] and the function [XmlDocument.transformNode] are not supported by this browser, can't transform XML document to HTML string!");
            return null;
        }

    }
}
var content = TransformToHtmlText(xml, xsl);
```

Comment: I like this solution.  However, with this I get the "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'atom'." error message.

Comment: @JohnChapman, [Check this](http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/29978-confused-about-xml-namespaces.html), could be helpful.

Comment: BTW, this all works perfectly in IE9, so I am thinking there is a new twist to all of this in IE10.  Just not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly credit to Roel van Lisdonk who published the function Sheik Heera shared.

I found this function as it was didn't work in Chrome, because of GetXmlStringFromXmlDoc() so I used the XMLSerializer:

So for example:

```
if (typeof(GetXmlStringFromXmlDoc)!= "undefined")
{       
    return GetXmlStringFromXmlDoc(xmlFragment);
}
else
{
    // chrome friendly

    // get a xml serializer object
    var xmls = new XMLSerializer();

    // convert dom into string
    var sResult = xmls.serializeToString(xmlFragment);
    //extract contents of transform iix node if it is present
    if (sResult.indexOf("<transformiix:result") > -1)
    {
        sResult = sResult.substring(sResult.indexOf(">") + 1, sResult.lastIndexOf("<"));
    }       
    return sResult;
}
```

The revised function is now:

```
function TransformToHtmlText(xmlDoc, xsltDoc) 
{
    // 1.
    if (typeof (XSLTProcessor) != "undefined") 
    {
        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
        var xmlFragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);

        if (typeof(GetXmlStringFromXmlDoc)!= "undefined")
        {       
            return GetXmlStringFromXmlDoc(xmlFragment);
        }
        else
        {
            // chrome friendly

            // get a xml serializer object
            var xmls = new XMLSerializer();

            // convert dom into string
            var sResult = xmls.serializeToString(xmlFragment);
            //extract contents of transform iix node if it is present
            if (sResult.indexOf("<transformiix:result") > -1)
            {
                sResult = sResult.substring(sResult.indexOf(">") + 1, sResult.lastIndexOf("<"));
            }       
            return sResult;
        }
    }
    // 2.
    if (typeof (xmlDoc.transformNode) != "undefined") 
    {
        return xmlDoc.transformNode(xsltDoc);
    }
    else {

            var activeXOb = null;
            try { activeXOb = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate"); } catch (ex) {}

        try {
            // 3
            if (activeXOb) 
            {
                var xslt = activeXOb;
                var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument");
                xslDoc.loadXML(xsltDoc.xml);
                xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
                var xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
                xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
                xslProc.transform();

                return xslProc.output;
            }
        }
        catch (e) 
        {
            // 4
            alert("The type [XSLTProcessor] and the function [XmlDocument.transformNode] are not supported by this browser, can't transform XML document to HTML string!");
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with IE 9 and none of the answers helped until I stopped trying to load the `xslt` file using `jQuery`.  I loaded the file with a script as documented in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

I was then able to use the `transformNode()` function.  Here is the script that they gave:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>sample</TITLE>
  <SCRIPT language = "javascript">
     function init()
     {
        var srcTree =
           new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
        srcTree.async=false;
        // You can substitute other XML file names here.
        srcTree.load("hello.xml"); 

        var xsltTree =
           new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
        xsltTree.async = false;
        // You can substitute other XSLT file names here.
        xsltTree.load("hello.xsl");
        resTree.innerHTML = srcTree.transformNode(xsltTree);
     }
  </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY onload = "init()" >
   <div id="resTree"></div>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```